# How to find least-mean-square error quadratic upper bound?

Tags: python, matlab, least-squares

I have some data of the form

`x1[i], x2[i], x3[i], z[i]`,

where `z[i]` is an unknown deterministic function of `x1[i], x2[i], and x3[i]`.  I would like to find a quadratic function `u(x1, x2, x3)= a11*x1^2 + a22*x2^2 + a33*x3^2 + a12*x1*x2 + ... + a0` that overbounds the data, i.e., `u(x1[i], x2[i], x3[i]) >= z[i]` for all `i`, and that minimizes the sum of the squared errors subject to the constraints.

Is there a computationally efficient solution approach in either Python or Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem sounds like a [quadratic programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) with linear constraints. There are efficient algorithms to solve these and they are implemented in Matlab and Python as well; see [`quadprog`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) and [CVXOPT](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/a/a7/Qp-cvxopt.pdf) respectively.

Comment: The constraints are indeed linear in the parameters.  I had not initially realized this.

Answer (score 1):

There is very simple solution. Just use polynomial regression in Mathlab (http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/polynomial-regression.html).
You will get a certain function P(x1[i],x2[i],x3[i]).
1. Then for each i compute expression Diff[i] = P(x1[i],x2[i],x3[i]) - z[i].
   You will get some array Diff. 
2. Select all the negative values.
3. Find the minimum value in Diff: M = Min(Diff).
4. The desired function is F(x1[i],x2[i],x3[i]) = P(x1[i],x2[i],x3[i]) + Abs(M), where Abs(M) - it's value excluding the sign of M.

But if you're not just limited to quadratic functions, you can vary the degree of the polynomial and eventually get a more precise solution.

Comment: Can you show that this approach minimizes the sum of squared errors with the constraints?

Comment: Hello Andrey,

Thanks for responding, but this approach doesn't work.  The following IPython session demonstrates a simple counter-example:

   In [1]: x= array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
   In [2]: y= array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

   In [3]: polyval(polyfit(x, y, 2), x)
   Out[3]: array([-0.08571429,  0.34285714,  0.48571429,  0.34285714, -0.08571429])

The center point is the one that requires the largest correction (1-0.4857= 0.5143).  If we shift the entire curve up by that amount, the quadratic is far above the end points.